# Mount local directory into Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to use Docker for a project where I do some data processing with Python. Let's say my code is in a directory called `code` (consisting of multiple python files for different steps of the analysation) and my data in a directory `data`. One solution would be to add the code and data like this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip
ADD code /code
ADD data /data
WORKDIR /code
CMD python
```

Then I could using `docker run -i someName pythonFile1.py` to run one of the files from `code`. But the problem I'm having here is that I need to rerun `docker build .` every time I change the code or the data.

So I tried to include these two Directories using `docker-compose` into volumes:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    myProject:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./data:/data
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM debian:stable-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip
WORKDIR /code
CMD python
```

Now I can run `docker-compose build` to build it, and then I thought I could just do `docker-compose run myProject pythonFile1.py`, but then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot start service tools: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"pythonFile1.py\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is docker-compose even the way to go (or could I achieve what I want just with a plain Dockerfile as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the docker-compose run documentation

```
run [options] [-v VOLUME...] [-p PORT...] [-e KEY=VAL...] SERVICE [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
```

pythonFile1.py is being interpreted as a command, thus when running, docker is trying to execute pythonFile1.py command inside the container which doesn't exist.

The docker-compose is not needed in your case. You can use the command

```
docker run -i someName -v /absolutePath/code:/code -v /absolute/data:/data pythonFile1.py
```

Note the paths on the host need to be absolute 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

Answer (score 2):

**Docker-compose with args avoid CMD**
So you have to add python command :

```
docker-compose run myproject python pythonFile1.py
```

---

**Explanation**

> docker-compose run SERVICE COMMAND

Where COMMAND don't use your CMD define in your Dockerfile.
You can create your Dockerfile without CMD or use it with `docker run`.

Maybe it's easier to understand when you try this command :

```
docker-compose run myproject ls .
```

because you can use whatever command you want, like `ls`, `ping`, `python` ...

Personnaly, I created a `python-cli.sh` who looks like :

```
docker run \
       --rm \
       -it \
       --privileged \
       -v $(pwd):/home/dev/app \
       -w /home/dev/app \
       python:3 \
       python "$@"
```

Then I make a link with `ln -S ./python-cli.sh /usr/local/bin/d-python`.
 And I use the command `d-python` as normal python command : `d-python myFile.py`